# In the MySQL WorkBench, when executing a Forward Engineering, an error 1064 appears in the log. Help me to understand

Tags: mysql

Executing SQL script in server

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VIRTUAL,
  `name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
  `place_of_birth` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
 ' at line 5
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `myBank`.`Clients`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myBank`.`Clients` (
          `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
          `name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
          `place_of_birth` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
          `date_of_birth` DATE NULL,
          `address` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
          `passport` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: I don't think you want the ID to be "GENERATED". Probably you want "AUTO_INCREMENT". But I don't know how and where to change it in Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports generated columns, but you must give an expression in the parentheses. It's not valid to say `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ()`.

If you intended to use ANSI SQL:2003 syntax for an identity column, MySQL does not support that syntax.

You can't make a generated column also be auto-increment.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html says:

> - The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute cannot be used in a generated column definition.
> - An AUTO_INCREMENT column cannot be used as a base column in a generated column definition.

For an identity primary key, you should use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myBank`.`Clients` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      `place_of_birth` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      `date_of_birth` DATE NULL,
      `address` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
      `passport` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```